# Accessing image pixel value

Tags: image, opencv, pixel

I want to return the value from a black and white image in opencv that has been rectified. I used `.type()` to see how to address `image.at<>(point())`. It gave back `0` so I put in `image.at<int>()`.

But all it gives back are numbers in the order of millions, instead of what I expect; something between `0` and `255`.

I used `.channel()` to check the number of channels; which was 1, so I think that should be ok.

What could I have been doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

"It gave back 0 so I put in `image.at<int>()`."

type==0 <--> that's uchar, not int.

try:

```
mat.at<uchar>(row,col);
```

instead

Answer (score 1):

If your data are `unsigned char` then index pixels as `img.at<uchar>(row,col)`

Comment: Thanks. I normalized it into floats, since uchar didn't seem to work for me;   normalize(image, dst, 0,255,NORM_MINMAX, CV_32F).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to normalize it to values between 0 and 255 beforehand? Using [cv::normalize](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/operations_on_arrays.html#cv-normalize), with alpha = 0 and beta = 255.